# Некорректно работает калькулятор на js

Tags: javascript

Сделал простенький калькулятор на `js`, всё работает нормально, кроме функции `Сложить`. Когда есть, например, ***5+5***, то получается не ***10***, а ***55***. Как это исправить?

```js
function f1() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById(`n2`).value;
  var result = num1 * num2;
  document.getElementById(`out`).innerHTML = result;
}

function f2() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById(`n2`).value;
  var result = num1 - num2;
  document.getElementById(`out`).innerHTML = result;
}

function f3() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById(`n2`).value;
  var result = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById(`out`).innerHTML = result;
}

function f4() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById(`n2`).value;
  var result = num1 / num2;
  document.getElementById(`out`).innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<p>Первое число:<input type="text" id="n1"></p>
<p>Второе число:<input type="text" id="n2"></p>
<button onclick="f1()">Умножить</button>
<button onclick="f2()">Вычесть</button>
<button onclick="f3()">Сложить</button>
<button onclick="f4()">Разделить</button>
<p id="out">Результат:</p>
```

Comment: Превратить строки в целые числа.

Comment: Картинка в тему: https://cs7.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2018/05/24/4/1527137831117322350.jpg

Comment: @ВасяВасинн ParseInt не надо. Вдруг там дробное число будет.

Comment: @ВасяВасинн не стоит вандализировать свои вопросы

Answer (score 5):

Ты должен приводить все значения к типу Number.

```
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById(`n1`).value);
var num2 = Number(document.getElementById(`n2`).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все значения полей в JS - строки. Нужно их привести в Integer.
Это можно сделать такими способами:

```
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById(`n1`).value);
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById(`n1`).value);
```

Так же, в целях економии места (хахаха) можно пользоватся приведением типов:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value * 1;
var num1 = document.getElementById(`n1`).value + 0;
var num1 = +document.getElementById(`n1`).value;
```